# Find nodes with css-selectors:query

Tags: html, css, lisp, common-lisp

I'm having trouble getting `css-selectors:query` to work.
Totally didn't understand what args go in and in what order. 
http://quickdocs.org/css-selectors/

Looking at the source code:

```
(defun query (inp &optional (trees buildnode:*document*))
  "Given a css selector, attempt to find the matching nodes in the passed in
   dom-trees (defaults to the document)"
  (%query inp trees))
```

I don't know what `inp` stands for but by process of elimination assume it to mean a css selector string.

```
(defun get-page (url)
  "Get STP(DOM alternative) representation of page"
  (chtml:parse
   (drakma:http-request url)
   (cxml-stp:make-builder)))

(css-selectors:query "a" (get-page "http://lisp.org/")) ; Doesn't work
(css-selectors:query (get-page "http://lisp.org/") "a") ; Worth a try
```

Example usage will greatly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Quickload `css-selectors-stp` to get it working with STP.

I contacted the author and the documentation has been made more clear. Support for STP should have been merged in and complete but the author wrote this package for DOM and has never used STP. So it SHOULD work for STP but doesn't for whatever reason.

The following works:

```
(defun get-page (url)
  "Get DOM representation of page"
  (chtml:parse
   (drakma:http-request url)
   (cxml-dom:make-dom-builder)))

(css-selectors:query "a" (get-page "http://lisp.org/")) ; Success!
```